# How to add array inside array and call them out

Tags: php, arrays

Below is array stored in session. It works finely.

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$sum_1]=array('car_id'=>$car_id,'location'=>$location,'dropoff'=>$d_location,'date_value'=>$date_value,'date_value_2'=>$date_value_2,'total_days'=>$total_days,'addon'=>$addon);
?>
```

And I call them out like this,

```
 foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $total=>$id)
 {
    echo $total;
    echo $id['addon'];
 }
```

Now I want to add another array inside the above array to include `date_from` and `date_to` for 
addon items (`$id['addon']`).

How can I do that and then call them out according to `addon_id`?
This is the part that stores addon items id in the array for now:

```
'addon'=>$addon
```

EDITED

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$sum_1]=array('car_id'=>$car_id,'location'=>$location,'dropoff'=>$d_location,'date_value'=>$date_value,'date_value_2'=>$date_value_2,'total_days'=>$total_days,'addon'=>$addon,array('d_from'=>$date_from,'d_to'=>$date_to))
```

Comment: Please explain in brief what you want to do

Comment: @Utkarsh I Want each addon to have date_from and date_to So that when it display each addon, it will display the date_from and date_to as well.

Comment: @clarkson Yeah well, that's what you wrote in the question, but where do date_from and date_to come from ? And what would be the desired array ouput ?

Comment: Why don't you just add more fields to the existing array: `addon_date_from` and `addon_date_to`, then echo `$id['addon_date_from']`, etc.

Comment: You need a key for the new element you added to the array in the edit. Something like `'addon_dates' => array(...)`. But I still don't see why this should be a sub-array, and not just elements in the first array.

Comment: The array consists of specific car info and that car can have many addons and each addon has date_from and date_to thats why I need sub array

Comment: @ClémentMalet, I think you would my point if you looked at the edited part? Is that a correct way of creating sub array?

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $total=>$id)
 {
    echo $total;
    foreach( $id['addon'] as $key=>$value)
    {   
       echo "$key - $value";
    }
 }
```

I assumed the dates were in $addon already. If not you can just add a variable to the array you already have, like

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$sum_1]=array('car_id'=>$car_id,'location'=>$location,'dropoff'=>$d_location,'date_value'=>$date_value,'date_value_2'=>$date_value_2,'total_days'=>$total_days,'addon'=>$addon,'dates'=> array('d_from'=>$date_from,'d_to'=>$date_to))
```

or

```
$dates = array('d_from'=>$date_from,'d_to'=>$date_to);
$_SESSION['cart'][$sum_1]=array('car_id'=>$car_id,'location'=>$location,'dropoff'=>$d_location,'date_value'=>$date_value,'date_value_2'=>$date_value_2,'total_days'=>$total_days,'addon'=>$addon,'dates'=> $dates)
```

In that case you have to replace 'addon' with 'dates' in the first code example.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the wanted output

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $total=>$id)
{
  if ($id['addon'] == $wanted_addon_to_add_dates) {
    $array['date_from'] = $date_from;
    $array['date_to'] = $date_to;
    $id[(whatever your want here)] = $array;
  }
}
```

And just a suggestion to give more sense to your code.
It will gives you an array like

`array ('var'=>value, ..., array ('addon'=>addon_id, 'date_from'=>date_from, 'date_to'=>date_to))`

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $total=>$id)
{
  if ($id['addon'] == $wanted_addon_to_add_dates) {
    $array['date_from'] = $date_from;
    $array['date_to'] = $date_to;
    $array['addon'] = $id['addon'];
    $id['addon'] = $array;
  }
}
```